# Multiple base map in Qfield?

Tags: qgis, geopackage, basemap, qfield

Is it possible to load 2 base maps in Qfield (both of the 2 rasters are in geopackage format), and choose wich one I want to see and maybe switch during the field work ? I tried with the map themes but it does'nt seems to work with rasters.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I found the solution here: [No sync geopackage raster layer to QFIELD](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348416/no-sync-geopackage-raster-layer-to-qfield?rq=1)  ! Even if I checked the option "relative path" in the project properties in QGIS, it seems that QFIELDSync still exported my project.qgs with absolute paths for rasters.
I try to explain how I did it: I opened my "project.qgs" directly in the mobile folder with notepad, and changed all the paths coresponding to my computer folders with the paths of my mobile folders (replace by "./raster.gpkg").
At this time it work for me !

Answer (score -1):

You can configure Map themes in your project in QGIS and then using it in qfield.

Comment: Hi and welcome to GIS.SE! Could you please add more details to your answer so that other users can benefit from it too?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried it. It works with vector layers, but I would like to be able to switch between different background layers (for exemple photos, or maps). In the map themes, only the vectors are visible. Anyone have the same issue ?